Is there a way to inject CSS properties inline with Thymeleaf?
Im structuring an email in the backend with Spring and Thymeleaf, and i have come across the following problem: I need to inject a color hex code as a CSS property while using inline CSS.
<span 
  th:text="${newStateText}" 
  style="display: inline-block; padding: 0.35em 0.65em; font-size: .75em; font-weight: 700; line-height: 1; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: baseline; border-radius: 1rem;" 
  th:style="'background-color: '+${newStateBackgroundColor}+'; color: '+${newStateColor}+''"
                        >
</span>

As you can see, im trying to use something like th:style which does not exist (i think) to inject the newStateBackgroundColor and newStateColor context variables
I expect to be able inject some style properties by variable and also keep my styles inline.

Try th:attr="style=...". Merge your existing style values with this one.

Thank you very much! that did it, but with th:attrappend, so i first defined my styles={} normally, and then defined th:attrappend with the variables

th:style does indeed exist.  I would recommend using literal substitution, like this:
<span 
  th:text="${newStateText}" 
  th:style="|background-color: ${newStateBackgroundColor}; color: ${newStateColor}; display: inline-block; padding: 0.35em 0.65em; font-size: .75em; font-weight: 700; line-height: 1; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: baseline; border-radius: 1rem;|" 
/>

